# Fuzzy score to include only best match found in query text - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have multiple words in query text that are close to word "Raquel" which in indexed in field1.
The problem is that score increases as the number of terms increases in query text.

To elaborate:

- if query text is "Raquel", score is 5 (let's assume)
- if query text is "Raquei", score is 4.9 (let's assume)
- if query text is "Raquel Raquei Raque", the score increases, lets say (15). I need this score to be 5. Just the best score from amongst all scores evaluated against all query terms for a specific term in a field. Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Here's the query:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "multi_match": {
            "query": "Raquel Raquei Raque",
            "fields": ["filed1", "filed2"],
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "minimum_should_match": "1"
            }}]
            }
}
```

Mappings for the fields used in query:

```
"filed1": {
 "type": "text",
 "analyzer": "standard_rebuilt",
 "index_options": "docs"
 },
 "filed2": {
 "type": "text",
 "analyzer": "standard_rebuilt",
 "index_options": "docs"
 }
```

where standard_rebuilt uses unique word filter

Comment: Can you please clarify? you're asking how to give `field1` more importance than `field2`?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert No, both fields have same importance. I edited the question as well, let me know if any further explanation is needed